# How to avoid default alert when using OpenUrl with tel://2373829239

Tags: iphone, ios

How do you avoid the default iOS alert when using OpenUrl with tel://2373829239?

I am getting a push notification with a number and options such as 'Call' and 'Cancel'. When the user presses 'Call' again a default iOS alert appears which means the user has to press the 'Call' button twice to make a call. This is undesired so I was wondering how can I avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
NSString *callString;
callString = @"12345";
        NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:callString];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

OR

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:123"];
            NSString *escaped = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: This is what i am doing right now, and it is prompting me for a force alert Cancel, call

Comment: I am using second code of urlString, and its working, it does not pop up me anything, directly calls....

Comment: P.J - you mean if i remove // from tel:// it will not prompt me ?

Comment: P.J - Yes its a web view , and i am using
window.location.href="tel:8884563344"

Comment: and where is your question, you have asked that you are using web view?

Comment: What you can do is, trigger that url from UIWebView delegate and then call above code which I have mentioned in answer..

Comment: P.J - you are right its not prompting the alert :) Thanks, but why this biased thing if i m calling it through the javascript, its a call anyhow right ? that too by tel:734284399 not by tel://328329299
i will try ur suggestion by reading in delegate method of UIWebView and try to handle, hoping if anything direct from javascript ?
anyhow Thanks a lot, i can see a hope :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid this situation. Apple want their iOS to help you avoid making a phone call by accident, which sounds sensible to me.

Comment: oh, there should be something like Android where you have the option for direct call or prompt alert call :( Apple are you listening :) Thanks Occulus

Comment: Hi Naren, yes it's all down to what Apple want their iOS to do. If you had a jailbroken device, you might have more options.

Comment: @occulus Are you sure, if we write in code with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL... , it asks for call option prompt?

Comment: Yup I am sure that is the case!